# jupyter_sphinx :linenos: option does not have any effect

Tags: python, jupyter, python-sphinx

Following a simple recipe:

1. Create the simplest Sphinx project via sphinx-quickstart in an empty root directory
2. Leaving everything at default
3. Add "jupyter_sphinx" to the extensions list in conf.py
4. Add a simple block of Python code to index.rst as per the extension's documentation:

```
.. jupyter-execute::
   :linenos:

   print('foo')
   print('bar')
   print('baz')
```

5. Do `make html` at the root dir

The resulting index.html does not show any line numbers.  I've tried enabling the configuration options `jupyter_sphinx_linenos` and `jupyter_sphinx_continue_linenos` to no effect.  What is missing here?

`jupyter_sphinx` version -> 0.2.4

Answer (score 0):

The problem may be that you need to add `extensions = ["jupyter_sphinx.execute"]` in `conf.py`. I am not able to reproduce the error.

Comment: I am able to reproduce the problem (Python 3.8.0, Sphinx 3.1.2, jupyter_sphinx 0.2.4). With `extensions = ["jupyter_sphinx.execute"]`, I get this warning: "while setting up extension jupyter_sphinx.execute: `jupyter-sphinx` was initialized with the `jupyter_sphinx.execute` sub-module. Replace this with `jupyter_sphinx`. Initializing with `jupyter_sphinx.execute` will be removed in version 0.3".